# Problem to put google adsense ads on site in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, adsense

I have a problem placing google adsense ads on the site in next js

I found these codes on the internet but it is not working. I do not know what else to do

The first code is a component in which it is to be placed wherever there is an advertisement

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Adsense() {
  const loadAds = () => {
    try {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("adsense error", error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ins
      className="adsbygoogle"
      style={{ display: "block" }}
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
      data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
      data-ad-format="auto"
      data-full-width-responsive="true"
    ></ins>
  );
}
```

The second is to put in _document.js

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" />
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
            `,
            }} />
```

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 AdSense head tag doesn't support data-nscript attribute.

Comment: Finally, did you solve it? Same issue here.